# How do I pass an instance's transformation matrix to vertex shader input?

Tags: 3d, directx, hlsl, direct3d

I tried decomposing my transform into four vectors, and reassembling them on the shader, but it doesn't seem to work. My transforms are wrong, and my objects don't show up. Please help!

Here is my input format:

```
D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC inputElementDescriptor[] =
    {
        { "POSITION",   0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 0, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA,      0 },
        { "TEXCOORD",   0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_FLOAT, 0, 12, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA,         0 },
        { "TEXCOORD",   1, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_FLOAT, 0, 20, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA,         0 },
        { "NORMAL",     0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 76, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA,      0 },
        { "RowX",       0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT, 1, 0, D3D11_INPUT_PER_INSTANCE_DATA,  1},
        { "RowY",       0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT, 1, 16, D3D11_INPUT_PER_INSTANCE_DATA, 1},
        { "RowZ",       0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT, 1, 32, D3D11_INPUT_PER_INSTANCE_DATA, 1 },
        { "RowW",       0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT, 1, 48, D3D11_INPUT_PER_INSTANCE_DATA, 1}
    };
```

Here is my instance data:

```
struct RenderableInstanceData
// This really has no business being inside D3D code.
{
    FASTVEC rowX;
    FASTVEC rowY;
    FASTVEC rowZ;
    FASTVEC rowW;
};
```

Here's how I buffer it up:

```
{
    if (this->m_pInstanceBuffer)
        delete this->m_pInstanceBuffer;

size_t numInstances     = this->m_pInstances.size ();

if (this->m_pInstanceBuff)
    delete [] this->m_pInstanceBuff;
this->m_pInstanceBuff   = (CORE_BYTE *)malloc (sizeof (RenderableInstanceData) * numInstances);
for (size_t idx         = 0; idx < numInstances; idx++)
{
    auto pInstance      = this->m_pInstances[idx];
    RenderableInstanceData data;
    pInstance->ToInstanceData(data);
    memcpy (&this->m_pInstanceBuff[idx], (const void *) &data, sizeof(data));
}
D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA _instanceData;
_instanceData.pSysMem   = m_pInstanceBuff;
this->m_pInstanceBuffer = DirectX11Buffer::CreateInstanceBuffer (pDevice, (UINT) sizeof (RenderableInstanceData), numInstances, false, &_instanceData); // We only keep the transform for an instance for now.
}
```

Here is the shader:

```
struct DirectionalLight
{
    float4 colourAmbient;
    float4 colourDiffuse;
    float pad;
    float3 direction;

};

cbuffer cbPerFrame
{
    DirectionalLight light;
    matrix CameraMatrix;
    matrix ViewProjectionMatrix;
};

StructuredBuffer<DirectionalLight> lightBuffer;
Texture2D ObjTexture;
SamplerState ObjSamplerState;

struct VS_INPUT
{
    float4 position: POSITION;
    float2 texCoord0: TEXCOORD0;
    float2 texCoord1: TEXCOORD1;
    float3 normal: NORMAL;

    float4 rowX: ROWX;
    float4 rowY: ROWY;
    float4 rowZ: ROWZ;
    float4 rowW: ROWW;
};



struct VOut
{
    float4 position : SV_POSITION;
    float2 texCoord : TEXCOORD;
    float3 normal: NORMAL;
};

VOut VShader (VS_INPUT input)
{
    VOut output;

    float4x4 world      = float4x4(input.rowX, input.rowY, input.rowZ, input.rowW);
    float4x4 MVP        = world * ViewProjectionMatrix;

    output.position     = mul (input.position, MVP);
    output.texCoord     = input.texCoord0;
    output.normal       = mul (input.normal, world);

    return output;

}
```

And, here is how the camera and view projection are calculated:

```
this->m_FrameUniforms.Camera                = this->m_CameraView;
                this->m_FrameUniforms.ViewProjectionMatrix  = (this->m_CameraView * cameraViewProjectionMatrix);
                auto pUniformBufferPointer                      = this->m_pUniformBuffer->GetRawPointer ();
                this->m_pDeviceContext->UpdateSubresource (pUniformBufferPointer, 0, NULL, &this->m_PerObjectBuffer, 0, 0);
                this->m_pDeviceContext->VSSetConstantBuffers (0, 1, &pUniformBufferPointer);
```

Answer (score 1):

In the end, I did a modification in the shader. Here is the final code:

```
VOut VShader (VS_INPUT input)
{
    VOut output;

    float4x4 world      = float4x4(input.rowX, input.rowY, input.rowZ, input.rowW);
    float4x4 MVP        = mul(mul((ProjectionMatrix), transpose(CameraMatrix)), transpose(world));
    output.position     = mul (input.position, MVP);
    output.texCoord     = input.texCoord0;
    output.normal       = mul (input.normal, world);

    return output;

}
```

There were two things that helped. One, I remembered that HLSL has a different method of storing matrix than the math library on the CPU side, so I needed to transpose my matrices. Two, it seems that multiplying two matrices such as

```
matA * matB
```

is not the same as multiplying them such as

```
mul(matA, matB)
```